# how to auto refresh the idToken when using firebase auth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase for authentication in my Next.js app and also I have an express server that serves a REST API, which has a middleware that uses `firebase-admin` to verify `idToken` that is sent from my app, to pass the authenticated routes

**Currently**

The idToken generated by firebase lasts for one hour and if the client is still on my app and
hits any route that needs `idToken` and if the `idToken` is expired then the server just throws an error as unauthenticated, which is pretty good work, but this is not desired, I know my user is in there and just `idToken` is expired

**Question**

How do I refresh my `idToken` of a user if it has expired, without having to do a full refresh in the browser to get new `idToken`

**Some Code**

```
AuthContext.tsx

/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import nookies from 'nookies'
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { axios } from '../config/axios'
import firebase from '../config/firebase'
import { AuthUser } from '../types'
import { BaseUser } from '../types/user'
import { getProvider } from '../utils/oAuthProviders'

type AuthContextType = {
  user: AuthUser | null
  login: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<any>
  signup: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<any>
  logout: () => Promise<any>
  oAuthLogin: (provider: string) => Promise<any>
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>({} as AuthContextType)
export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext)

const fromPaths = ['/login', '/signup']

const formatUser = (user: BaseUser, idToken: string): AuthUser => {
  return {
    ...user,
    idToken,
  }
}

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<AuthUser | null>(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const router = useRouter()
  console.log(user)

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        user
          .getIdToken()
          .then(async (idToken) => {
            try {
              const userResp = await axios.get('/user/me', {
                headers: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`,
                },
              })
              nookies.set(undefined, 'idk', idToken, { path: '/' })
              const {
                data: { userFullDetials },
              } = userResp
              setUser(formatUser(userFullDetials, idToken))
              setLoading(false)
              if (fromPaths.includes(router.pathname)) {
                router.push('/home')
              }
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(err)
              setUser(null)
              setLoading(false)
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message)
            setUser(null)
            setLoading(false)
          })
      } else {
        setLoading(false)
        setUser(null)
      }
    })
    return () => unsub()
  }, [router])

  const login = (email: string, password: string) => {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }

  const signup = (email: string, password: string) => {
    return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }

  const oAuthLogin = (provider: string) => {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(getProvider(provider))
  }

  const logout = async () => {
    setUser(null)
    await firebase.auth().signOut()
  }

  const returnObj = {
    user,
    login,
    signup,
    logout,
    oAuthLogin,
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={returnObj}>
      {loading ? (
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-full h-screen bg-gray-100">
          <h1 className="text-indigo-600 text-8xl">S2Media</h1>
        </div>
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

```
// auth.ts
// Auth Middleware in express

import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express'
import fbadmin from 'firebase-admin'
import { DecodedIdToken } from '../types/index'

export default async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const authorization = req.header('Authorization')
  if (!authorization || !authorization.startsWith('Bearer')) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      status: 401,
      message: 'authorization denied',
    })
  }

  const idToken = authorization.split(' ')[1]
  if (!idToken) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      status: 401,
      message: 'authorization denied',
    })
  }

  try {
    const decodedToken = await fbadmin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
    req.user = decodedToken as DecodedIdToken
    return next()
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
    return res.status(401).json({
      status: 401,
      message: 'authorization denied',
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Firebase SDK does that for you. Whenever you call `user.getIdToken()` it will return a valid token for sure. If the existing token has expired, it will refresh and return a new token.
You can use `onIdTokenChanged()`and which will trigger whenever a token is refreshed and store it in your state.

However, I don't see any cons in using `getIdToken()` method whenever you are making an API request to server. You won't have to deal with IdToken observer and get valid token always.

```js
const makeAPIRequest = async () => {
  // get token before making API request
  const token = await user.getIdToken()

  // pass the token in request headers
}
```

Right now your code makes a request to server to get user's information whenever a token refreshes and that may be redundant.

Comment: so you are saying to use `user.getIdToken()` every time before sending a request to server

Comment: @sairaj yes. If existing token is valid, it'll return that else return a refreshed token.

Comment: and because `idToken` is changed `onIdTokenChanged()` will fire and that will update my state

Comment: @sairaj do you really need the id token observer? Like do you need to update something when a token is refreshed?

Comment: @sairaj then I'd recommend use getIdToken() whenever you need to make API request rather than using onIdTokenChanged. That's not necessary.

Comment: so I think it is better to use just `onAuthStateChange()` listener if I am not wrong, because I want to get data of the logged-in user and their profile

Comment: @sairaj yes, and use `getIdToken` when you need the token.

Comment: Yes, Thank you @Dharmaraj, it really helped